# Add or remove product to given websites using product_action model

Tags: product, attributes, websites, action

The following example sets price and name of product only for given store ID:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

//Load product 100 from store 2
$product->setStoreId(2)->load(100);

//Set product price and name
$product->setName('Train ticket');
$product->setPrice(4.65);

//Remove website 6, add website 8, then save
$product->setWebsiteIds(array_diff(array_merge($product->getWebsiteIds(),[8]),[6]));
$product->save();
```

It works perfectly but Magento copies unchanged store-specific attribute values in database that do not differ from base values (they are the same as in default store 0). To avoid redundant data, you can use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes([100], [
    'price' => 4.65,
    'name' => 'Train ticket',
], 2);
```

But how to add or remove website IDs this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
$actionModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$actionModel->updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteIds, 'add');
```

If you want to remove the websites, use 'remove' as a third parameter.

When you add the product to websites, I'd suggest to leave out the websites the product is already added to. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Website::addProducts` first executes a remove command for the product / website combinations so if the products have been assigned to the website before your operation will take longer.